# Assembler kernel32.dll

Tags: assembly, kernel32

I want find kernel32.dll.(win xp 32bit SP3, x86).

This is my MASM code:

```
.586p
.model  flat,stdcall

.code

START:
 assume fs:nothing
 xor ebx, ebx               
 mov ebx, fs:[30h ]       
 mov ebx, [ ebx + 0Ch ]  
 mov ebx, [ ebx + 14h ]    
 mov ebx, [ ebx ]           
 mov ebx, [ ebx ]           
 mov ebx, [ ebx + 10h ]    

end START
```

This show me in Olly:
`EBX 7C800000 kernel32.7C800000`

Is it real kernel32.dll address or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not to call `LoadLibrary` to obtain kernel32's base address?

Comment: I would guess he's trying to create a shellcode